# jQuery 1.8.x IE7 .append() .prepend() Problems

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I've seen this same combination of words used all over SO but **not one of them** addresses the underlying problem of *jQuery* and *IE7* just not getting along.
My application runs without error on every major browser and versions of IE greater than 8. However, a lot of my corporate users still are made to suffer with the anemic excuse for a browser known as IE7. While recently testing, I came across this strange error...

[image: IE7 complains about jQuery's append and prepend]

This is clearly a complaint about jQuery itself and one that I thought had been eradicated with jQuery v1.3.x? So, my question is:

**Is there a workaround? Am I supposed to find each occurrence of `.append()` and `.prepend()` in my app and replace them with something less elegant?**

Answer (score 2):

Future readers of this post should bear witness that the **SCRIPT65535** error in jQuery when using IE8 or lower is an indication that a DOM node is being accessed that is normally outside of the scope of jQuery's realm. In my case, I was attempting to change the `<title>` of the page using `.text()`.

This is a well-known and unresolved bug with jQuery and IE, as seen here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7825

Be sure to check your code for references to nodes that typically exist outside of the `<HTML>` tag such as `<FRAME>`, `<HEAD>`, `<TITLE>` or `<IFRAME>` and you will most likely find your problem.